# How to rotate "landscape" pages to view in "portrait" mode?

Tags: adobe-reader

Is it possible to configure Adobe Reader to display the pages, which were set to landscape mode, in portrait mode (while rotating their content, of course)?

It is annoying that while scrolling through a document, the page zoom changes abruptly when reaching a landscaped page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the page view changing, then you can set the zoom level to a specific amount instead of something like "Fit Width".

To change the pages from landscape to portrait would require cropping them, not rotating them (unless you want to also rotate the content!) I'm not aware of any free PDF reader that would allow you to do that.

Comment: Thanks. "unless you want to also rotate the content" - that's basically what I asked for in the question. Do not crop anything, just rotate.

Comment: BTW, if you're using the Hand Tool to click and drag pages in order to scroll them, then using non-auto zoom value gets the page also move left and right. Rotating pages will eliminate this annoyance.